# update Trigger gives invalid statement

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have this trigger in sqlite which is giving invalid statement error
I am trying to update the table orders after a payment has been inserted.
The trigger looks for all payment with the payments orderid, sums it, and update the total in the orders

payments table

```
Amount
ID
OrderID
```

Orders Table

```
ID
Paid
Bal
```

The trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_order_total]
AFTER INSERT
ON Payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Orders Set Orders.Paid =(Select SUM (Amount) From Payments Where  OrderID = Orders.id ) WHere id = new.ID;
UPDATE Orders Set Orders.Bal = Orders.Paid - (Select SUM (Amount) From Payments Where  OrderID = Orders.id ) WHere id = new.ID;
END
```

**EDIT**

I made edit to the trigger, the first statements now works, but the second update statement doesn't

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_order_total]
    AFTER INSERT
    ON Payments
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Orders Set Paid =(Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID) WHere Orders.id = new.ID;
UPDATE Orders Set Bal = Paid - (Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID) WHere Orders.id = new.ID;
END
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I finally solved myself with the following statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_order_total]
AFTER INSERT
ON Payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Orders Set Paid =(Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID),PayMethod =new.PayMethod  WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;
UPDATE Orders Set Bal = Total - (Select SUM (Amount) From Payments AS p Where p.OrderID  = Orders.ID) WHere Orders.id = new.OrderID;

END
```

Regards